# Inquiry regarding how often to convert a JS object to JSON format used to store data in a hidden text field residing on a PDF form

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, text, stringify

Unlike most, I am presently using a JS object to store data used to populate (text) form field values residing on an interactive PDF form. To make this work, the JS object is converted to a JSON string stored inside a hidden (text) form field. The JSON object is parsed and converted to a JS object when the PDF form first opens ready for use. This noted, I am wanting to know if it's actually necessary to stringify and save the JS object in JSON format to the hidden (text) form field following each and every change made to the data stored in the JS object or is it sufficient to wait until the session ends when the PDF form is closed/saved and no longer in use to stringify and save the JS object to the hidden text form field? Your response to this inquiry is most appreciated. Thank you ahead of time.

Not applicable as the answer to be provided is based on preference and common practice.